# create-react-app Not Working !! events.js:292 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am getting this **error** while trying to use

```
create-react-app folder-name
```

Same type of error occurs when when I use following code

```
   npx create-react-app folder-name
   cd folder-name
   npm start
```

**Error**

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Manoj Mukthavaram\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd.exe',
  path: 'cmd.exe',
  spawnargs: [
    '/d',
    '/s',
    '/c',
    '"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use npx create-react-app . // (dot)

once you create project folder and see that your are in your current folder

Comment: Nope! Not working. Actually do you have any documentation for that "dot". I think its just adding dot to end of folder name

Comment: ' . ' (dot ) say to install react app in current folder , i mean say if your project folder is in e drive , then in terminal move to you project folder ex- e:\project-folder> then try installing using npx create-react-app . ex:- e:\project-folder> npx create-react-app .